# Unable to resolve module url from cloudinary

Tags: node.js, npm, cloudinary

I am building a React Native app and tried to simply:

```
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
```

However, I keep getting an error:

```
Unable to resolve module url from node_modules/cloudinary/lib/config.js: Invalid directory /Users/node_modules/url
```

I have tried many of the suggestions for the Github thread on this including rebuilding the project, however, I still get the same error.

My gut is that this has something to do with the way lodash or other modules are being required. The same issue happened when I tried to require passport but not async.

What am I missing here? Any advice on what to look for when npm'ing files would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No I just uploaded to s3